# Discord.py 2.0.0a member.avatar.url?as

Tags: python, discord.py, avatar

I'm using discord.py 2.0.0a early,
So I used to use this command for resizing user avatar: *`Pillow Lib`*

```py
pfp = user.avatar_url_as(size = 512)
data = BytesIO(await pfp.read())
pfp = Image.open(data).convert("RGBA")
pfp = pfp.resize((407,407))
```

I use this to paste the avatar with 407 size into an image.

Which now member avatar URL changed to `member.avatar.url`,

So I need help with how to do the same function above for Discord.py 2.0.0a.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use `user.avatar.with_size(size=512)` in **discord.py 2.0** according the [actual documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Asset.with_size).

Comment: The documentation link you provided doesn't exist